# When to put space between a tag name and a class or id

Tags: css

When should I be using this:

```
header.classname
```

and when should I use this:

```
header .classname
```

And what is the difference between the two?

Comment: Even though there is nothing wrong with posting this question here, I do suggest following a CSS starter tutorial. It'll get you through the basics and most tutorials teach you stuff like this as well. I've heard good things about http://codecademy.com, but you could also try http://csstutorial.net, or the infamous w3schools css tutorial. Or have a go at google to find one in whatever language and style you want. (get it, style?)

Comment: The difference is what the documentation says it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`header.classname` mean you are targeting header having class as `classname`.

`header .classname` mean you are targeting the html element having class `classname` which is a child/descendent of header

**1st case:**

```css
header.hclassname {
  background: turquoise;
}
```

```html
<header class="hclassname">
  Lorem Ipsum
  <div class="divclassname">Dolor</div>
  Sit Amet
</header>
```

**2nd case**

```css
header .divclassname {
  background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<header class="hclassname">
  Lorem Ipsum
  <div class="divclassname">Dolor</div>
  Sit Amet
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `header.classname` when: you want to target a `.classname` that is a `header` element.

Use `header .classname` when: you want to target `.classname` descendants of a `header` element.

I hope this solves your question, it's as simple as can be.